# What is the mean of NUM_LOADER_THREADS and NUM_WRITER_THREADS in sysbench-mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sysbench

I use the sysbench-mongodb to test the performance of mongodb, and the tool has a config file named config.bash. In this file has two parameter:

```
# total number of simultaneous insertion threads (for loader)
#   valid values : integer > 0
export NUM_LOADER_THREADS=8

# total number of simultaneous benchmark threads
#   valid values : integer > 0
export NUM_WRITER_THREADS=64
```

I do not know what's the difference between these two parameter. Who had used these tool? Anyone can help me? Thank you.